# How to receive invoke multiple tasks and collect task status with Django/Celery

Tags: django, task, celery, status

I am setting up multiple tasks in my tasks.py, and calling the tasks from views.py. I want to invoke all the different tasks in a for loop so I can collect the status easily and build a progress bar. I am able to invoke all the tasks line by line currently (as shown below).

Here are my questions: how do I invoke the different tasks from views.py in a for loop? it always give me an error of "unicode does not have attribute delay()". Or is there a better way to collect the statuses of different tasks and build the progress bar from them?

I have tried to invoke the functions in views.py like this:
   for i in range (1, 6):
       functionName = "calculation" + str(i)
       functionName.delay(accountNumber)
But this gives an error as stated above "unicode does not have attribute delay()"

my guess is that the tasks are imported from tasks.py to views.py

my current tasks.py:

```
@shared_task
def calculation1(arg):
     some action here

@shared_task
def calculation2(arg):
    some action here

@shared_task
def calculation3(arg):
    some action here

@shared_task
def calculation4(arg):
    some action here

@shared_task
def calculation5(arg):
    some action here
```

my views.py:

```
result_calculation1= calculation1.delay(accountNumber)
result_calculation2 = calculation2.delay(accountNumber)
result_calculation3 = calculation3.delay(accountNumber)
result_calculation4= calculation4.delay(accountNumber)
result_calculation5 = calculation5.delay(accountNumber)
```

I want to collect all the tasks statuses in a for loop, so I can build a progress bar, but if there is any other better suggestion on collecting task status and building a progress bar , that's great.

Thank you very much for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getattr()` to retrieve the functions from the `tasks.py` module once you've built the names:

```
from myapp import tasks  # Make sure you import the tasks module

for i in range (1, 6): 
    functionName = "calculation" + str(i)  
    task = getattr(tasks, functionName)  # Get the task by name from the tasks module
```

After you've retrieved the task function, you can build up a list of signatures:

```
signatures = []
signatures.append(task.s(accountNumber))  # Add task signature
```

From the signatures you can create a group and execute the group as a whole:

```
from celery import group

task_group = group(signatures)
group_result = group()  # Execute the group
```

And from the `group_result` you can access each individual task result and build the progress bar around that (perhaps iterating the results in `group_result` and checking each result's `status`):

```
for result in group_result:
    status = result.status
    # Your progress bar logic...
```

Putting it all together:

```
from celery import group
from myapp import tasks  # Make sure you import the tasks module

signatures = []

for i in range (1, 6): 
    functionName = "calculation" + str(i) 
    task = getattr(tasks, functionName)  # Get the task from the tasks module
    signatures.append(task.s(accountNumber))  # Add each task signature

task_group = group(signatures)
group_result = group()  # Execute the group

for result in group_result:
    status = result.status
    # Your progress bar logic...
```

Comment: Thank you will, the for loop is working well. I need to work on the status part further, I will come back to update later on.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the tasks into a [group](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/reference/celery.html#celery.group) and you can receive a [GroupResult](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.GroupResult). you can refer to [celery doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/reference/index.html)